# Unable to merge two firebase arrays in Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I am relatively new to Swift/Firebase and I am struggling to merge two arrays so that the downloadURL is seen amongst both the name and the email fields. One function adds the name and the email through the button click the other is another function to save the URL. When I try and merge them I get this (as seen in the image below). Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func createAccountAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let Users = Database.database().reference().child("Users")

    let userDictionary : NSDictionary = ["email" : emailTextField.text as String!, "Name": nameTextField.text!]

    Users.childByAutoId().setValue(userDictionary) {
        (error, ref) in

        if self.emailTextField.text == "" {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter your email and password", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

                if error == nil {
                    print("You have successfully signed up")
                    //Goes to the Setup page which lets the user take a photo for their profile picture and also chose a username

                    var imgData: NSData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((self.profilePicture?.image)!, 0.8)!)
                    self.uploadProfileImageToFirebase(data: imgData)


                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
                    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

                } else {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 func addImageURLToDatabase(uid:String, values:[String:AnyObject]){
    let Users = Database.database().reference().child("Users")
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com/")

    Users.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error)
            return
        }
        self.parent?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: One of your set calls is using `childByAutoId()` while the other one is trying to set the value for a child of `uid`, which, if it doesn't exist, will be created. So, you can move your 'setValues` call to after the user is created.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried changing the code however I am running into some errors would it be possible if you could show me the implementation. I would be extremely grateful

Comment: Sure, show your updated code. I'll try to help you

Comment: Hi I've updated the code but I'm running into multiple errors like Value of type 'SignUpViewController' has no member 'uploadProfileImageToFirebase' and Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

Comment: I tried calling the function after the user was created however that provided even more errors

Comment: Did you update the code in your question? I don’t see any change

Comment: I only updated the addImageURLToDatabase function, does that seem correct now?

Comment: No, that is not right. Let me write up an example quickly. Will come back to you with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is what you want. I removed a few variables from your function but you can add them back. I just wanted to make sure the code compiles.

```
@IBAction func createAccountAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users")

    let userDictionary : NSDictionary = ["email" : emailTextField.text!, "Name": nameTextField.text!]

    if emailTextField.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter your email and password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.emailTextField.text ?? "", password: self.passwordTextField.text ?? "") { (result, error) in
            if error != nil {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }

            // HERE YOU SET THE VALUES

            usersRef.child(user.uid).setValue(userDictionary, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil { print(error); return }
                self.addImageURLToDatabase(uid: user.uid, values: ["Put": "Your Values Here" as AnyObject])
            })

        }
    }
}
func addImageURLToDatabase(uid:String, values:[String:AnyObject]){
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(uid)
    usersRef.updateChildValues(values) { (error, ref) in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error)
            return
        }
        self.parent?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope it helps!! BTW I saw that you have a function `self.uploadProfileImageToFirebase` which is probably calling `addImageURLToDatabase`. So change that in the code of the answer. I didn't do it because I don't have that method from your question

Comment: Your code seems to make sense however I keep getting the error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:) Cannot store object of type FIRDatabaseReference at . Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: self.addImageURLToDatabase(uid: user.uid, values: ["downloadURL": usersRef])

Comment: userRef is a reference to the database. You need the string of the downloadURL. Try "TestString" just to check if it writes where it should and then you can figure out how to add the downloadURL string

Comment: Thank you so much the test string works I think I can get the downloadURL string. One last thing do you know how to reorder the values within the array. Dont worry if you don't know I'm sure I'll figure it out. Thank you once again for your patience.

Comment: What do you mean reorder? Please accept the answer if it was helpful

Comment: By values I mean the name, email and downloadURL, for some reason when I look in the database the Name value comes first then the downloadURL and then the email

Comment: Name is capital so it will always be first in the database, then it will be ordered alphabetically between downloadURL and email. The only way they can be ordered is alphabetically if you set your keys as lowercase or uppercase for all of them. Firebase does it automatically. Not much you can do about it. That doesn't really make any difference for your queries anyway